# Semigroups related to iterated orthogonal complement

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids

Let $R\subset V\times V$ be a relation on a set $V$. For a subset $S\subset V$, define *its orthogonal complement with respect to $R$*
as
$$S^l:=\{ x: \forall y\in S\ \ (x,y)\in R\},\ \ S^r:=\{y: \forall x\in S\ \ (x,y)\in R\},\ S^{lr}:=(S^l)^r,...$$

For two words $u,v$ in alphabet $\{l,r\}$, write $u =_{V,R,S} v$ iff  $S^u=S^v$.
Thus, $l=_{V,R,S} lrl$ and $r=_{V,R,S} rlr$.

This is the usual orthogonal complement when $V$ is a vector space and $R:=\{(u,v):\phi(x,y)=0\}$ for a bilinear form $\phi(-,-)$.

Fix $R$, and define a semi-group $O_{V,R}:=<l,r: u=v\ \text{ if }\ \forall S\subset V\ u=_{V,R,S}v  >$ with two generators $l,r$ and relations $u=v$ whenever  $\forall S\subset V\ u=_{R,S}v$.
The relations
$l=_{V,R,S} lrl$ and $r=_{V,R,S} rlr$ seem to hold only for the two generators, and in particular, it seems these semi-groups are not necessarily regular.

What is known about the regular semigroups of this form ? Have they been studied ?
Is there a name ?

I am particularly interested in the case when $V$ is the set of morphisms of a category,
and $R$ is the weak ortogonality relation, also known as the lifting property.

The simplest non-trivial case of interest is as follows: $X$ is the set of continuous maps in the category of topological spaces,
and $R$ is the weak orthogonality relation, and $S:=\{ \emptyset\to \{pt\}\}$ is the class consisting of a single map from
the empty set to a singleton.

Is something known when $V$ is a vector space and $R$ is a possibly non-symmetric bilinear form ? (I thank @BenjaminSteinberg for corrections).

Comment: Are you sure the semigroup is regular?   It isn't enough for the generators to be regular.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: Yes, I think so, though it requires a little argument. Here is a (corrected) argument.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg:  Let $u^T$ denote the result of replacing each letter $l$ by $r$, and each $r$ by $l$, i.e.
        $l^T:=r$, $r^T:=l$, and $(xy)^T:=x^Ty^T$. Let $S^{-1}:=\{(y,x): (x,y)\in S\}$.




        Then $u=_{S,R}u u^T u$, as follows from the following.

        $S^r = ((S^{-1})^l)^{-1}$, and, more generally, $S^u=((S^{-1})^{u^T})^{-1}$.
        This implies that 
        $l=_{S^u,V} lrl$ means that $ul=_{S,V} ul u^T r ul = (ul) (ul)^T (ul)$.

Comment: What does S^{-1} mean?

Comment: The inverse of $S$: $S^{-1}:=\{ (y,x)\in V\times V: (x,y)\in S\}$. That is, $(x,y)\in S$ iff $(y,x)\in S^{-1}$.

Comment: But $S$ is a set not a relation

Comment: Also, I don't believe what you define is actually a semigroup if you leave $S$ fixed.  Your equivalence relation, as I understand it, is that the free monoid on l and r act on the right P(V) by your definition above.  But then, the equivalence relation is only a right congruence and not a congruence.  Just because $S^u=S^v$, I don't see any reason why $S^wu=S^wv$.  I think you would get a congruence if you define u equivalent to v if T^u=T^v for all subsets T of V.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: Oh, you are right.  It is not a semi-group. And what I wrote using $S^{-1}$ is nonsense, and is unfixable. I meant to use take orthogonals with respect to $R^{-1}$, but do not see now how it might helps. Let me edit the question as you suggest.

Comment: This is somehow related to residuation theory by Blyth and otehrs, but because your Galois connection reverses order, I am a bit confused.  You might look at the paper Regular monoids generated by two galois connections by  Martin Skorsky,  Semigroup Forum volume 39, pages 263–293 (1989). He looks at something similar to what you do but not exactly the same.  He gets a regular semigroup out of this and you might look at his section 2 for ideas.

Comment: I think the issue here is that your r,l are order-reversing and order-reversing galois connections are a bit messy under composition.